# Bootstrap 4 - Column to row on small display

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Have a grid with 4 columns and 4 rows. What I want to happen is on a small display the 4th column becomes a 5th row on a small display vs the column that it is on a medium+ display. It's a pet project to try and understand the bootstrap grid layout better. I'm essentially making a responsive calculator for the practice. I feel like I could do this with just raw CSS but figured bootstrap had to have some utilities that would make this easier. Images for example.

Large format:

[image]

Small format:

[image]

I have a start for the markup. There is some more associated CSS but I don't think it's important in the example. I've had a few versions but this is where I'm at in the moment.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">6</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">9</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-light">&plusmn;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-light">.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I can only pick one solution as an answer but kiranvj, WebDevBooster, and dferenc all provided Bootstrap 4 release version working solutions. I can only mark one as an answer. No slight to the rest of you guys. My hands are tied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the simplest possible markup is the one below. It also uses the [Order classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes), but instead of setting the order of every button explicitly, this one touches just the "extra" buttons in the last column with `.order-last .order-sm-0`.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">3</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 order-last order-sm-0 btn-lg btn-secondary">X</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">6</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 order-last order-sm-0 btn-lg btn-secondary">-</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">9</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 order-last order-sm-0 btn-lg btn-secondary">+</button>

        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">&plusmn;</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-lg btn-dark">.</button>
        
        <!--
        Use `col-12 col-sm-3` in case you want a full-width `=` button 
        In that case you could omit `.justify-content-center` at the wrapper
        -->
        <button type="button" class="col-12 col-sm-3 order-last order-sm-0 btn-lg btn-secondary">=</button>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would do something like this. Check in full screen mode and resize to small

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
      <div class="col-4">black</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-danger">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">pink</div>
       <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">pink</div>
       <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">pink</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, I do see that it works. I'm a little curious about how `col-sm-12` works in this case. Shouldn't they actually each take up the full row and fold down under each other on a small display? Columns are 12 slots wide after all, no? I take it the `col-4` plays a role in that behavior...

Comment: `col-sm-12` is for small and above devices to show one below other

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create 3 additional pink div elements that render below the black divs, and then hide them using the `hidden-*-up` and `hidden-*-down` classes.  When the screen is small, hide the pink divs on the right and show the pink divs on the bottom, and vice versa when the screen is small.

Comment: here is a link that explains it better https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: Is there some reason why you are referencing the alpha docs? Bootstrap 4 is in **release**!

Comment: Looks like the bulk of hidden classes were dropped in the release version. I could probably use the `.d-` classes for the same effect though.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to build a calculator, I took a slightly different approach than my esteemed colleagues and created a grid that looks, feels and quacks like an actual calculator. I hope you aren't too mad about that. :-)

The main job is done by using the re-ordering classes. Those allow moving things around based on your breakpoint needs.

For example, the class combo `order-3 order-md-1` says:

"Normally i.e. from the smallest screen size onwards you're gonna go to position #3 but from the medium (`md`) screen size and up you're gonna go to position #1."

And since the neighboring HTML elements also have `order-1` as their default position, that element is gonna appear in the same order **on medium sized screens** as the neighbors. But on smaller than `md` screens that element is gonna become a "third-class citizen" and will, therefore, be positioned after the element with the `order-2` class.

The `<div class="w-100"></div>` elements are just handy dividers. `w-100` means "width:100%".

Speaking of dividers: I've noticed that your calculator has no division button, but I hope you'll figure out what to do about that.

Finally, you hadn't specified what to do with the equal sign button. So, I took the liberty to change its appearance on smaller screens. That is accomplished by first hiding the default button using the `d-none d-md-block` classes and then having a wider version of it appear using the `d-md-none` class. That last class basically says: Hide it (display:none) from `md` screens and up.

Here's the working code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-3 order-md-1">&times;</button>
                <div class="w-100 order-1"></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">6</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-3 order-md-1">&minus;</button>
                <div class="w-100 order-1"></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-3 order-md-1">+</button>
                <div class="w-100 order-1"></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-light text-dark order-1">&pm;</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1">0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-light text-dark order-1">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-outline-dark order-1 d-none d-md-block">=</button>
                <div class="w-100 order-2"></div>
                <div class="w-100 order-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 col-sm-4 pl-0 pr-0 pr-sm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark order-4 d-md-none">=</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I also was intending to leverage the placement classes too to get the order the way I intended when the column collapsed into a row.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if this solution works best for you. :-)